# Confusion about how to set .env variable in node.js/express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, environment-variables

So I've been trying to connect to my MongoDB database, and I had to make a process.env.MONGO_URI variable to store the connection URI, and I was getting very frustrated because it wasn't working when I was seemingly doing it correctly according to my learning modules' instructions, the code below:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MONGO_URI='mongodb+srv://myUsername:myPassword@cluster0-7impo.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

The above wasn't working despite what the "solution" said, but when I changed the code to this it worked,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MONGO_URI='mongodb+srv://myUsername:myPassword@cluster0-7impo.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
process.env.MONGO_URI='mongodb+srv://myUsername:myPassword@cluster0-7impo.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

My main question is about setting the process.env.VARIABLE, why do I have to set the CAPITALIZED part on a separate line and then reset the full process.env.VARIABLE again on a separate line? My learning materials basically said you set it and then you can sort of "clip it on" to the process.env, which seems completely wrong, or is there multiple ways of setting the process.env. variables, could someone give me a better explanation please, thank you geniuses of stackoverflow

Comment: You can just do :: `const mongoose = require('mongoose');
process.env.MONGO_URI='mongodb+srv://myUsername:myPassword@cluster0-7impo.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });` (don't need 2nd line) though in real world applications you won't store DB connection string like what you're doing here..

Comment: Have you installed .env? Is utilizing env variables a requirement of yours? It's not a requirement to connect to Mongoose. You should be able to change `mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, ...` to `mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, ...` and remove the `process.env.MONGO_URI=...`, it should connect.

Answer (score 3):

In the first example you are defining the `var MONGO_URI` and then using the `process.env.MONGO_URI`; this is incorrect because you have to use the variable you have already defined `MONGO_URI` directly inside the `connect` method or use the variable from the .env file in the root directory of your project. You can use one of the following scenarios:

**1) Local Variable Case:** Add a var or const like you have done before and then attach it to the connect method of mongoose:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MONGO_URI='mongodb+srv://myUsername:myPassword@cluster0-7impo.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

**2) Using `.env` File Case:** Add the connection string as variable in the `.env` file in the root directory of your project:

create a `.env` file and it should contains the following:

```
MONGO_URI = 'mongodb+srv://myUsername:myPassword@cluster0-7impo.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

Then you can include this variable inside you connect method but first you have to install the `dotenv` npm package through one of these commands:

**With npm:** npm install dotenv

**With Yarn:** yarn add dotenv

Then include the dotenv package inside your main project file: `require('dotenv').config();`

The final step is to add the variable from the .env file to your connect method and the final result should look like that:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) module.

You need to create a .env file in your project root directory.